# When should we use Combine's multicast autoconnect()

Tags: swift, combine, reactivex

I have this code

```
import Foundation
import Combine

let upstreamPublisher = Just("Hello, World!")
let sharedSubject = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("initial value")

// Create a multicast publisher and apply autoconnect
let multicastPublisher = upstreamPublisher
    .multicast(subject: sharedSubject)
    .autoconnect()

// Subscriber 1
multicastPublisher
    .sink { value in
        print("Subscriber 1 received value: \(value)")
    }

// Subscriber 2
multicastPublisher
    .sink { value in
        print("Subscriber 2 received value: \(value)")
    }
```

The output is:

```
Subscriber 1 received value: initial value
Subscriber 1 received value: Hello, World!
```

I read from an article that `The first time you subscribe to it, it connects to the upstream publisher and starts the work immediately. This is useful in scenarios where the upstream publisher emits a single value and you can use a CurrentValueSubject to share it with subscribers.`. The first part makes sense to me, but I don't know what the second part of the sentence really means. How can we share the results with current value subject and autoconnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we share the results with current value subject and autoconnect?

This is already what your code is doing!

I assume you expected subscriber 2 to also receive the initial value and "Hello, World!", i.e. an output like this

```
Subscriber 1 received value: initial value
Subscriber 2 received value: initial value
Subscriber 2 received value: Hello, World!
Subscriber 1 received value: Hello, World!
```

This doesn't happen because `Just` publishes synchronously. As soon as you call `sink`, the subscriber is automatically connected to `multicast` (because `autoconnect`). As a result, `Just` publishes its value and completes immediately. When you add the second subscriber, everything is already completed and it doesn't receive anything.

You can see this happening by adding `.print("Subscriber 2")` before `sink`. The output is:

```
Subscriber 2: receive subscription: (Multicast)
Subscriber 2: request unlimited
Subscriber 2: receive finished
```

If you turn the upstream into a publisher that doesn't publish values asynchronously, e.g. a network request, timer, `delay`, etc, then both subscribers get values:

```
let upstreamPublisher = Just("Hello, World!")
    .delay(for: 1, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
```

Make sure you store references to the `AnyCancellable`s somewhere or the publisher will get cancelled before "Hello, World!" is published!

---

Of course, there is always the option of calling `connect` manually.

Comment: Thanks! Yes this makes sense, once the behavior subject is completed, it will not fire its value to the new subscribers. Previous I thought it will always relay the last value no matter it completed or not.